# how to put images from JSON file to React Native Js page

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I need to put the images from JSON file to my React Native Page. Below is my code:

```
 <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems:'center' }}>
                       <Image source={{item.image}} style = {styles.imageView}/>
                 <View style={{  flex: 1, alignItems: "center"}}>
                        <Text  style={styles.Address1}>{item.addr} </Text>
                </View>
            </View>
```

I can read other things from my JSOn file like item.addr is coming from json file, but not sure how to read the image. I tried writing my json file like this:

```
 {

        "addr": "124 test drive, Ring road",
        "phone": "(951)-955-6200",
        "LatL":"33.977880",
        "Long2":"-117.373423",
        "cLat": "33.931989",
        "cLong": "-117.409222",
        "Online": "https://www.test.org",
         "image" : "require(\"CAC.png\")"
     }
```

I also tried writing image like below in my JSON file

```
"image" : "require('../images/CAC.png')"
```

It seems, it is reading blank image: below is the screen shot:

[image]

Below code is working, but in this case, I am writing a constant image rather than reading from json file.

```
 <Image source={require('../images/CAC.png')} style = {styles.imageView}/>
```

My code is in a directory called  Modules that resides in project directory directory. My project name is test and my Json file is in a directory called Reducers and reducers also resides in project directory and my images are in a directory called images that also resides in the project directory. below is the path:

```
c:\MobileApplication\test\Modules\ServiceListDetails.js
c:\MobileApplication\test\reducers\ServiceDetails.json
c:\MobileApplication\test\images\CAC.png
```

My project name is test. below is my imageView style

```
imageView:{
width:'30%',
height:100,
margin:7,
borderRadius: 7

},
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hey man you are writing the require function in the json as a string. Try to remove the quotes.

Comment: Now I have this my JSON file: "image" : "require(../images/CAC.png)"  still I cannot see any image

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Be sure that your image's name is correct in your json file. For instance, .png instead .PNG, and then you need something like this:

Firstly create a component to load your icons:

```
c:\MobileApplication\test\Modules\Icons.js
exports.CAC = require('../assets/images/CAC.png');
exports.CAD = require('../assets/images/CAD.png');
exports.CAE = require('../assets/images/CAE.png');
```

Secondly import your Icons inside your component:

```
c:\MobileApplication\test\Modules\ServiceListDetails.js
import Icons from './Icons';
import resources from './ServiceDetails.json';
```

Finally:

```
  <Image source={Icons[resources.image]} style = {styles.imageView}/>
```

Now you have to change o json with the code you want.

```
    "image": "CAC"
}
```

Or

```
   "image": "CAD"
}
```

Or

```
 "image": "CAE"
}
```

Comment: According to [react-native docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html) this is a bad way to do this and I am not sure this will work properly or not

Comment: You're right @MasoudTavakkoli! I edited and tested here. It works!

Comment: Once I did this, I cannot see any image at all.

Comment: @Anjali could you put your project structure here. if you use require('../images/CAC.png') in image tag it works? Also what do you have in your style styles.imageView?

Comment: Hi Gasper, In edited my post above putting the directory structure

Comment: I also put the style sheet

Comment: Hi there. Take a look here: https://snack.expo.io/@gasparteixeira/dynamic-images I think it will help you!

Comment: Hi Gasper, I did all the steps that you mentioned above, but still, I cannot see the image. I am not sure what am I doing wrong. I also tried to open the link that you provided above and the link is not opening as well. Please let me know if you need any additional information.

Comment: Thank You Gasper, I was making a mistake,. I was putting CAC.png in my json file instead of CAC. Thank You again for all your help!!

Comment: Glad it helped you!

Answer (score 5):

By Facebook [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html) you can do it by two method.

**First:**

by STATIC images as you use before but some changes needed in your JSON. Rewrite your object like this

```
{
    "addr": "124 test drive, Ring road",
    "phone": "(951)-955-6200",
    "LatL":"33.977880",
    "Long2":"-117.373423",
    "cLat": "33.931989",
    "cLong": "-117.409222",
    "Online": "https://www.test.org",
    "image" : require("CAC.png") // <-- This line
}
```

and use it Like this

```
<Image source={item.image} style = {styles.imageView}/>
```

**Second:**
if you get this JSON from external server, you should get image from server too.

```
{
    "addr": "124 test drive, Ring road",
    "phone": "(951)-955-6200",
    "LatL":"33.977880",
    "Long2":"-117.373423",
    "cLat": "33.931989",
    "cLong": "-117.409222",
    "Online": "https://www.test.org",
    "image" : "https://example.com/path/to/your/image.png" // <-- This line
}
```

use it Like this

```
<Image source={{uri: item.image}} style = {styles.imageView}/>
```

**UPDATE:**

for this issue you can do this.

Json is like this

```
{
    "addr": "124 test drive, Ring road",
    "phone": "(951)-955-6200",
    "LatL":"33.977880",
    "Long2":"-117.373423",
    "cLat": "33.931989",
    "cLong": "-117.409222",
    "Online": "https://www.test.org",
    "image" : "CAD" // <-- This line
}
```

And the function

```
getImage = (image) => {

    switch (image) {
        case "CAD":
            return require("CAD.png")
            break;
        case "CAD2":
            return require("CAD2.png")
            break;
        case "CAD3":
            return require("CAD3.png")
            break;

        default:
            return require("CAD4.png");
            break;
    }
}
```

And

```
<Image source={this.getImage(item.image)} style = {styles.imageView}/>
```

Comment: when I put require("CAC.png") in my JSOn file, I am getting an error saying [Json] value expected. I tried doing "image" : "require(\"CAC.png\") ". Still don't see any image on the phone, but the space is created.

Comment: I made the edits to my code. Still, I am seeing the image on my phone.

Comment: Please see my original post for the edits that you told me

Comment: @Anjali if number of images is limited you can use a `switch` that give a key from json and return `require(...)` something like @gaspar said

Comment: Yes, number of images are limited. Do you have any example for switch statement

Comment: The second one was the one I was looking for! Thanks bud!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and after research I managed to solve it by putting the JSON data in a constant in JS, with that I was able to import the image and only inform the import in the JSON object. Example:

```
import imageImport from './image.png';

export const example = [
  {
    "name": "example",
    "image": imageImport
  }
]
```

---

```
<Image source={example.image}/>
```